# Авторизация на сайте

Tags: php

Привет всем! Пытаюсь произвести авторизацию на сайте http://l2top.ru/login/

> <?php
>
> $post
> ="backurl=http%3A%2F%2Fl2top.ru%2F&actLogin=logine&ab=bd&fa=dv&rememb=1&login=tophope&pass=tophope";
>
> $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch,
> CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array(
> 'Content-Type:
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded' )
> ); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,
> 'http://l2top.ru/login/' );
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
> $post); $result = curl_exec($ch);
> curl_close($ch);
>
> if(strpos($result,"Приветствуем
> evalGUI")===false) die('Приветствуем!
> Вы можете войти или
> зарегистрироваться');
>
> echo $result;
> ?>

Но что-то никак не получаеться, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: CURLOPT_HEADER 1 поставь посмотри что по заголовкам

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$post ="backurl=http%3A%2F%2Fl2top.ru%2F&actLogin=logine&ab=bd&fa=dv&rememb=0&login=tophope&password=tophope";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://l2top.ru/login/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt"); //Из какого файла читать
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt"); //В какой файл записывать
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array( 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://l2top.ru/login/' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

#if (strpos($result, "Приветствуем evalGUI") === false) die('Приветствуем! Вы можете войти или зарегистрироваться'); #По неизвестным мне причинам, эта проверка не работает

echo $result;

?>
```